# Opencv image is contorted after finding contours

Tags: opencv, contour

After finding contours in an image, the image changes. Is there a reason for this?

`myContours, myHierarchy = cv2.findContours(inputImage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588801/cvfindcontours-is-modifying-source-image-opencv-2-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV contours affect the source image. If you do not want to change the source image I suggest you make a copy of the input image. Something like:

```
myContours, myHierarchy = cv2.findContours(inputImage.copy(), # This creates a copy of the original image and any changes will not affect your original image
cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```